# Quais as diferenças entre Kanban e Scrum?

Tags: metodologia-ágil, scrum, kanban

Parece que hoje em dia é impossível trabalhar em programação e não conhecer as **metodologias ágeis** de desenvolvimento.
Tenho noção de que ambas são usadas para melhorar o desempenho e integração da equipe ao desenvolver código, porém tenho dificuldade de diferir essas metodologias. 
Minhas dúvidas são:

- O que difere entre Kanban e Scrum?
- Existem outras metologias ágeis? Nunca ouvi falar de nenhuma outra fora essas 2.
- Como escolher entre Kanban e Scrum? Existe algum fator que possa ser decisivo na escolha da metologia para equipe?

Comment: O kanban é usado dentro do scrum para fazer gestão à vista

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado então não é uma metodologia em si? só uma parte do scrum?

Comment: Me expressei mal =x Kanban e scrum são dois seres distintos, com focos diferentes. Kanban foca no acompanhamento visual dos processos, muito usado no sistema lean de produção. Scrum é um esquema de gerência de projetos, focado em curtas corridas (sprints) e contato constante com os stakeholders

Comment: estou com preguiça, tô deixando a semente para alguém responder... pode ser por chat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scrum é um método de desenvolvimento ágil que conta com componentes característicos como:

- a divisão do tempo de desenvolvimento em sprints onde as estregas são feitas de maneiras graduais e independentes umas das outras.
- Um integrante do time (Product Owner) deve ter a função de integrar as demandas dos clientes da aplicação/área de negócios com o time de desenvolvimento e Scrum Master.
- Um integrante do time (Scrum Master) é o responsável pelo time de desenvolvimento e pelos Product Owners, devendo saber das habilidades e limitações do seu time, auxiliar no desenvolvimento mais efetivo possível e evitar interferências.

Kanban nada mais é do que uma maneira de organizar o desenvolvimento, originalmente feito com post-its e hoje em dia também em meios digitais.
Separando colunas que representam os estágios do desenvolvimento e os post-its com o nome da tarefa ou da sprint escrita.

Por exemplo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existem outros modelos ágeis e empresas adaptam os métodos ágeis para encaixar no seu contexto.
 Um exemplo de outro método é o Extreme Programming(XP)

Comment: Não mesmo, esse que tu se refere é o "kanban", que seria algo "sinal visual", herdado do TṔS. O Kanban é sim uma metodologia, bem documentada pelo David Anderson ainda em 2008 e com muito conteúdo disponível. Veja por exemplo em http://leankanban.com/

Answer (score 2):

Cada metodologia ágil trás um conjunto peculiar de condições, vantagens e desafios para sua adoção em ambiente corporativo.

Antes de escolher sugiro que avalie criteriosamente os prós e contras contextualizando a cultura da empresa, os problemas atuais de desempenho e se haverá apoio interno para mudança.

Algumas outras opções interessantes para estudar são:

1. Lean
2. AUP (Agile Unified Process)
3. FDD (Feature Driven Development)
4. Scrumban
5. Crystal
6. DSDM

Comment: `Lean` é ágil? Pensei que fosse só um jeito mais eficiente da gestão tradicional

Comment: Os princípios do Lean harmonizam com a proposta Agile. O artigo em anexo aborda as conexões entre Lean e Agile: https://www.forbes.com/2010/01/11/software-lean-manufacturing-technology-cio-network-agile.html